# Android - browser and download notification

Tags: java, android

If I use "intent" to download a file with Android browser like that:

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://myserver.com/picture1.jpg"));
startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

Can I catch some event when the browser finish the download?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to implement your own `WebView`. Once you have done so, you must set a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and overwrite the [`onPageFinished`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.